# Во время работы - запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в таком примере: "Во время работы системы(,) не следует отвлекаться".

Спасибо!

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, мотив необходимости запятой.

Comment: В документации мне постоянно приносят такие тексты, где стоят запятые тут. Хотелось проверить. Благодарю.

Comment: Не прибегая к правилам, здесь вопрос запятых можно снять перестановкой: *Не следует отвлекаться во время работы*.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь!